# Get tab index from ContextMenu in android

Tags: android, eclipse, tabs

I added a context menu to tabs, I want to close the tab when user click on menuitem "Close Tab". But I am unable to get the index of tab on which user longpress. Here is my code.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu (ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Options");
        menu.add("Close Tab");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected (MenuItem item) {
        if (item.toString().equals("Close Tab")){
             TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
             int index = code required ?????????
                     int Itemcount = tabHost.getTabWidget().getTabCount();
             if (Itemcount > 1){;
                  tabHost.setCurrentTab(index);
                  tabHost.getTabWidget().removeView(tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(index));
             }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

use item.getTitle()...try this

```
  @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected (MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getTitle().toString().equals("Close Tab")){
         TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
         int index = code required ?????????
                 int Itemcount = tabHost.getTabWidget().getTabCount();
         if (Itemcount > 1){;
              tabHost.setCurrentTab(index);
              tabHost.getTabWidget().removeView(tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(index));
         }


    }
```

Comment: thanks, but I was looking for "code required ?????????" part. To get index of currently touched tab.